# python3 and psycopg2, checking dict_valus and dict_keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I keep doing this:

```
if isinstance(parameters, collections.abc.KeysView) or isinstance(parameters, collections.abc.ValuesView):
```

In order to check whether a param to be passed on to pscycopg2 is a `dict_values` or `dict_keys` and I'm wondering: is there a shorter way?

Super trivial here but that's a lot of characters.

Comment: Maybe create a tuple in application code with both types in there and pass that to `isinstance()`? Not sure there is a built-in way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isinstance` can take a tuple of types:

```
from collections.abc import KeysView, ValuesView
isinstance(parameters, (KeysView, ValuesView))
```

Example:

```
x = collections.KeysView({'a': 'A'})
y = 1.333
print(isinstance(x, (KeysView, ValuesView)))
print(isinstance(y, (KeysView, ValuesView)))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```